# Http post to asmx with unnamed parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a webmethod like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string a)
    {
        return a;
    }
```

The instructions to post to my asmx webmethod say to post like this:

```
POST /Service1.asmx/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

a=string
```

However I want to be able to accept this:

```
POST /Service1.asmx/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

string
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? No standard tool will be able to communicate with your web service.

Answer (score 3):

This is more an issue of the HTTP POST protocol moreso than an ASP.NET issue.  The format of the POST body must be "variable=value;variable2=value2..."

Answer (score 0):

Just to restate this problem. I have a similar issue where a 3rd party tool posts a json object `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`

my .net code looks like

```
public bool AcceptPush(ABCObject ObjectName)
```

The 3rd party tool does not post `{ObjectName:{a:1, b:2, c:3}}` if it did there would not be any problem.

You could code the .net as this:

```
public bool AcceptPush(int a, int b, int c)
```

But in reality this is much uglier and the acutal object is much more complicated than this simple example